# Copying attributes from linear feature to point feature using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, identity

I have a segmented linear feature and a point feature.
I'm trying to transfer attribute information from the linear feature into the nearest point feature.

In the attached screenshot, the linear features have an attribute equal to 18 and 20. I'd like to copy that data into the nearest point features. So, the points close to the linear even with attribute equal "18" will get populated with "18". Points that are close to the linear even with attribute equal to "20" will get populated with "20".
I thought I can achieve that by using the Identity tool in ArcMap, but that did not work.
Which tool or tools do I need to use?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You can use the  Spatial Adjustment menu and use the Attribute Transfer Mapping. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-existing-features/transferring-attributes-between-features.htm

Comment: Spatial join or near, followed by join field will do

Comment: Near and Generate Near Table require an advanced license, spatial join is available at all license levels. Use the spatial relationship *closest* and your line fields will be appended to the points table https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000q000000 you could use the spatial join dialog in ArcMap to perform the join if you prefer.

Comment: Spatial Join did did the trick. Thank you all.